# Android facebook Api Exception

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-requests, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am getting facebook Api exception while logging in from my app, login is working in major of the  devices while in few of them it's giving below mentioned error :

> **Error ApiException**: Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.

Do anyone know how to fix this issue?